# how to find the average of first 3 rows using avg() function in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table called student, and which there is field of marks. i'm trying to get an average of first 3 marks.

```
    +-----------+
    |   MARKS   |
    +-----------+
    |   34.8771 |
    |   34.8282 |
    |   35.9533 |
    |      36.1 |
    |      36.3 |
    |     37.15 |
    +-----------+
```

I tried by following **query,**

```
select avg(marks) from student limit 3;
```

and i got following **output**,

```
+-------------------+
|    avg(marks)     |
+-------------------+
| 22.35627736719113 |
+-------------------+
```

i'm expecting the output as **35.21953333333333**

explanation, (34.8771+34.8282+35.9533)/3 **=** 35.21953333333333

Please help me with this.

Comment: What do YOU mean by "first three"?  SQL tables represent unordered sets and there is no "first" unless a column specifies the ordering.

Comment: i'm sorry, don't know this, i'm very new to database. please tell me how can get the average of first three rows if there is no ordering.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select avg(marks) from
(
Select marks from students limit 3
) as alias
```

Comment: Rows in a relational database represent unordered sets. There is no problem in SQL for which the above is an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You fist have to select the three rows that you want.

Then you can calculate the average

Of course the order of the MARKS mus be determined, by some order. And you **didn't provide** any means that explains your choice of numbers

```
SELECT AVG(MARKS) 
FROM
    (SELECT MARKS 
     FROM test
     ORDER BY MARKS desc
     LIMIT 3) t1
```